# How do I trigger an update of the data in the view?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m having some problems with updating data in my view. I have a service that returns data and I can see in the console it is fetching the newest post.

However, in my Ionic app the newest post is not displayed. I’m calling the service in ionViewDidEnter and I have even tried forcing the view to update using the NgZone in Angular. No solution has worked so far.
I have also tried to use applicationRef.tick() but has not helped either.

It works fine when in the browser when I disable cache. Then I can see the newest post. But it does not work on my device as no new data is displayed after it has cached the first data.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

This is my typescript file and you can see my Ionic info below.

```
/**
* @description this is where the data loads from the service. This 
  event always fires. It is a way of stopping caching in the app.
 */
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.loadItems();
});
}

 /**
  * @description loads all items
  */
 loadItems() {

// Create the loader
let loader = this.loadingController.create({
  content: "Getting data.."
});
loader.present();

// Get the most recent 100 posts
this.itemApi.getItems(100).then(data => {
  loader.dismiss();
  this.posts = data
  this.initializeItems();
});

}

/**
* @description set the new data equal to the items returned.
*/
 initializeItems() {
  // The data is reset to all items
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.items = this.posts;
  });
 }
```

My Ionic info:

```
cli packages: 

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.1.1
```

System:

```
Node : v8.10.0
npm  : 5.6.0
OS   : macOS High Sierra
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Comment: *It works fine when in the browser when I disable cache. Then I can see the newest post. But it does not work on my device as no new data is displayed after it has cached the first data.* The real problem likely has nothing to do with problem you stated. If this can replicated in browser with cache *enabled*, please, provide a way to replicate it. But since the problem is that data is cached, it doesn't matter how you trigger change detection (btw, you're doing it correctly, it should work). If it's cached, it's cached.

Comment: Alright. I just don't understand how to update the view or avoid caching. It was very simple in Ionic 1 but in this version it seems I'm unable to control it.

Comment: This totally depends on your case which isn't determinate. It's still unclear why and where caching takes place. From the question it appears that the problem can be replicated in a browser with cache enabled. This is what I asked about, *If this can replicated in browser with cache enabled, please, provide a way to replicate it.* In code-related questions, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary on SO.